# Is it mandatory to restart MongoDB after adding new index on collection?

Tags: mongodb

A MongoDB collection is slow to provide data as it has grown huge overtime.

I need to add an index on a few fields and to reflect it immediately in search. So I seek for clarification on followings things:

1. Is it mandatory to restart MongoDB after indexing?
2. If yes, then is there any way to add index without restarting the server? I don't want any downtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not need to be restarted after indexing.

However, by default, the createIndex operation blocks read/write on the affected database (note that it is not only the collection but the db). You may change the behaviour using **background** mode like this:

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { collectionKey: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

It might seem that your client is blocked when creating the index. The mongo shell session or connection where you are creating the index will block, but if there are more connections to the database, these will still be able to query and operate on the database.

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to restart MongoDB after you add an index!

However,an index could be created in the foreground which is the default.

What does it mean? MongoDB documentation states: ‘By default, creating an index on a populated collection blocks all other operations on a database. When building an index on a populated collection, the database that holds the collection is unavailable for reading or write operations until the index build completes. Any operation that requires a read or writes lock on all databases will wait for the foreground index build to complete’.

For potentially long-running index building operations on standalone deployments, the background option should be used. In that case, the MongoDB database remains available during the index building operation.
To create an index in the background, the following snippet should be used, see the image below.

[image]